# Asp.Net web form sometimes has strange mixing of HTML and JavaScript response in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, internet-explorer, webforms

I'm new to developing from scratch a new asp.net web forms application.

The problem: Everything works well on local and test servers. Deploying the application on the customer servers has some strange behavior.

Only with Internet Explorer and only sometimes, the response in the browser is incorrectly rendered. I see HTML repeated, JavaScript rendered directly on the screen, mixed with HTML in the wrong place.

All seems to happen at random.

Edit For Damon: I need 10 reputation to put images, this is how is bad rendered html only sometimes in ie:

```
    //]]>
</script>
```

```
??c?cr??|?04?*?9|u? ?*B?T߮?+mDp??}:?-?؉Ч????H?????:?t??dH$??D" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled txtSolaLettura" disabled="disabled" style="display:none">
            <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
            <option value="M">M</option>
            <option value="F">F</option>

        </select><input name="ctl00$cpHolderBody$GHOSTIndice§STRINGA§SD" type="text" maxlength="1" id="GHOSTIndice§STRINGA§SD" class="txtSolaLettura" readonly="readonly" /></td><td>Cognome Dichiarante</td><td class="STRINGA"><input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cpHolderBody$CTRLIndice§STRINGA§CD" id="CTRLIndice§STRINGA§CD" value="TextBox§Cognome Dichiarante§strtfrmtndfrmt§strtdcml0nddcml" /><input name="ctl00$cpHolderBody$JSONIndice§STRINGA§CD" type="text" maxlength="30" id="JSONIndice§STRINGA§CD" class="txtSolaLettura" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <0
```

TMȺ??OG?[?
@K??a?6%\?
J????-????߅
???^??y;hK?2cD?>?pK?O?tl00$cpHolderBody$CTRLIndice§STRINGA§ND" id="CTRLIndice§STRINGA§ND" value="TextBox§Nome Dichiarante§strtfrmtndfrmt§strtdcml0nddcml" />Codice Dichiarazione Anagrafica

Edit For Paul: wcf is rest, data sent and received is json

Don't know if this is important:

- In the application I frequently use ajax-jQuery calls to WCF services
- I (for example after an ajax call to redirect on other page) sometimes manually post the  forms (document.forms[0].submit()).
- I also have lots of jQuery code sometimes inside the page sometimes in external JS file.
- I also make use of a master page.

I'm thinking it could be involve server or client side caching...or server side buffering...

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post some code and some examples (screenshots perhaps) of where this happens?

Comment: Malformation of the HTML page could be because of the several reasons but at the bottom of it would most likely be due to quotation marks or some encoding conflict. This does not look like it could be a server issue.

Comment: What kind of data is being returned in the WCF out of curiosity?

Comment: I tried Damon suggestion, no result. In addition when I launch Fiddler it seems not to show again the problem, when I close Fiddler it does!!! --> I'm trying the application using a client connected with vpn to the lan in which is deployed the application

Comment: Another info the application is deployed on a server, there is server balancing the traffic before the server (there will be two server, now one is off), when I load application pointing to ip of the server balancing the traffic it seems to give the problem, when I point directly to the ip of the server in which is installed the application it seems not to show again the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab at this and guess that this is something to do with the Character encoding not being set correctly in the http header and the server setting the incorrect encoding when it is being rendered.

From this [page](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations):

> You should always specify the encoding used for an HTML or XML page.
>   If you don't, you risk that characters in your content are incorrectly
>   interpreted. This is not just an issue of human readability,
>   increasingly machines need to understand your data too. You should
>   also check that you are not specifying different encodings in
>   different places.

You could check this by using [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and examining the http headers being sent through.

I suggest specifying an encoding as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39d1w2xf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in MSDN.

From that page:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization
      fileEncoding="utf-8"
      requestEncoding="utf-8"
      responseEncoding="utf-8"
      culture="en-US"
      uiCulture="de-DE"
    />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```